# Mprotect set different permissions for each process

Tags: c, memory, permissions

I have a child process that creates a shared memory zone to which it should have write and read acess. I want the other child processes to have just read access.

However I can't seem to achieve this with mprotect.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: This should be possible with `mprotect()`. Where exactly does it fail? Can you provide the code?

Comment: @Ctx A child process would mprotect with read/write permissions. Then for each other child I would set read permissions for that memory zone. Even though the process that created the area was able to both read and write, the others weren't able to read. I am now trying something different where I create the shared memory before forking (with the size of n pages) and have each n child process mprotect a page on that shared memory. Even though the first page is protected, the others fail with "cannot allocate memory" (even though that range was mapped with mmap()).